# trait constraint on specific function rather than whole implementation

Tags: rust, traits, generic-function

I'm trying to implement a generic struct that can take any type parameter.

```
struct Position<T>{
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

impl<T:Num> Position<T>{
    fn add(&self, other: &Position<T>) -> Box<Position<T>>{
        box Position{x:self.x + other.x, y:self.y + other.y}
    }

    fn display(&self) -> String{
        "WELCOME ".to_string()
    }
}
```

now I can define

```
let original_position = Position::<int>{x: 2, y:23};
let another_postion   = original_position.add(&original_position);
let welcome           = original_postion.display();
```

without any error

similarly, i can do the following without any error.

```
let string_position = Position::<String>{x: "x_pos".to_string(), y: "y_pos".to_string()};
```

now due to the Num trait constraint i cannot call the following (which is obvious ).

```
string_position.add(&original_position);
```

but,my problem is that now i cannot call the following because of the same Num trait constraint

```
string_position.display()
```

the above function has noting to do with Num type, it simply returns the string "WELCOME"

**how do i need to rewrite the implemetation so that add method can be called only by `Position<Num>` and display can be called by any other generic implementation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create separate implementations, one with the bound and the other without, like this:

```
impl<T:Num> Position<T>{
    fn add(&self, other: &Position<T>) -> Box<Position<T>>{
        box Position{x:self.x + other.x, y:self.y + other.y}
    }
}

impl<T> Position<T>{
    fn display(&self) -> String{
        "WELCOME ".to_string()
    }
}
```

You can see that it works [here](http://is.gd/3pRn30).

Comment: I know it's YEARS later, but here's a "better" implementation of this problem, using Rust 1.62.1
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b60bd75fdb9d9841bd41a1cd0478b62